# Access denied for root user

Tags: ssh, debian, root

my ssh has started to refuse users from out of the blue. I started to connect via Putty as root, me and other users.

```
login as: root
root@31.XX.XX.XXX's password:
Access denied
```

What could be wrong? I didn't change anything.

Comment: Could you check your server logs ? You will find a more interesting information for debuging your problem

Comment: Can you post the output of `ssh -v server_ip`?

Comment: Thank you guys for the advices. I find out, that the root isn't in allowed groups. So, solved by editing /etc/ssh/sshd_config!

Comment: @Ginnyous Be careful with root login enabled - it's one less barrier for an attacker to overcome.

Answer (score 3):

By default root user is not allowed to login in SSH remote connection. Anyway I recommend you using a normal user to work, not root. You can always use sudo if you need it.